# Create numpy array once while having easy access

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am currently working with a large numpy array which contains several thousand elements.
The array is basically 'static' and is never modified. There are several functions that need this array and therefore I want to have easy access to it.
If I understood correctly it should be avoided to make variables global.
An easy way to get this array would be by creating a function that simply returns my array everytime I need it at different places in my code.
Is it correct to assume that a totally new numpy array will be created everytime I call the function?
What is a good way to circumvent this problem? I know that that the array will never change and therefore want it to be created only once while retaining easy access to it.
I think there is probably a very easy way of doing it that I totally miss.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.creation.html

arrays can easily be made with

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and, every time you call a function a new array will be made, yes, but if you are using the variable assigned with it you are just re-assigning it over and over